# CodeIgniter: Parse dynamic language captions located in javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter, translation, codeigniter-2

I have a javascript code that needs localisation, ie.

```
function js_proc() {
    var some_data = 'this text needs to be translated dynamically at runtime';
}
```

So I re-wrote like this:

```
function js_proc() {
    var some_data = <?php echo $this->lang->line('some_data_id'); ?>;
}
```

In the view, I wrote the js link like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="www.domain.com/codeigniter/get_js/file-1/"></script>
```

which calls the function get_js() in the controller. The idea is to have the get_js() function read the js file(s) and translate the language strings...

There are way too many js strings to be translated, so I can't pass `every string` as a variable. Ideally I'd like to make this work through the codeigniter language files.

**My question is: is there a way to parse the php parts in the js file & executed (=translate) them?** ie.

```
class App extends CI_Controller
{
    function get_js {
        $content = file_get_contents($js_file);
        echo parse_php($content);
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to use AJAX to achieve this. JS is called client side, so to use it's strings in PHP will be called after page load.  So, use an ajax call to hit a php script with the string that needs to be translated.

Comment: Thanks but as I said there are too many strings to localize :(

Comment: Pass the language ID/slug, so you only have to do 1.

Comment: You should use AJAX.

1. Create a Controller
2  Create a function that translates your POST data and returns an echo.

Comment: Try with `include($js_file);` inside the controller `get_js` function. It imports your script into the current scope and executes it there, so `$this` is your controller then.

Comment: @hakre: `js_file` is a javascript file, I can't **php include** it :(

Comment: @bigman: can you please expand on your idea, I'm not sure how can I do one single ajax query and parse strings in patch (PS. it's not just *one* js file, it's many actually)

Comment: @zer02: same question: can you please expand on your ideas, I'm not sure how can I call `$this->lang->line(...)` on the POSTed strings

Comment: @Gdhami: PHP is not specific about a file-extension, you can include any file you want. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php - What is true for HTML there is true for any other text as well. You *can* include JS files therefore, the PHP parts therein will be interpreted. See as well http://php.net/include

Comment: @hakre: Well what I meant is that there's javascript code in it, so it probably won't/can't be parsed by PHP. And even then, how can I echo it back to the browser? I mean, I can do: `$content = file_get_contents($js_file);` but **not** `$content = include($js_file);`

Comment: I would use jQuery AJAX to send each String to the controller and loop through all json objects( text strings ) and create a new array which have been filled with $this->lang->line(...) and send it back to my JS Function. Then update the text on my website or local variables

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how big the language file is, a quick way to allow javascript to access your entire language array could be to load the array into a global javascript array;

```
<script>
    var globalLang = <?php echo json_encode($this->lang->language); ?>;
</script>
```

Then access in your javascript like this;

```
globalLang['some_lang_key']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "There are way too many js strings to be translated, so I can't pass every string as a variable", but if you are looking for some automatic parsing, this won't help.

But this may help others, so here goes.

For from ideal, I use a system like the following:

In my view, I add the localizations as JavaScript global variables, using the codeigniter languages support.  Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var noEmailError = "<?php echo $this->lang->line('enter_your_email'); ?>";
</script>
```

Then after that, usually,right after, I include the scripts that refernce the globals:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/validate.js"></script>
```

inside the script:

```
alert(noEmailError);
```

will show the localized text just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json object in the global scope of the page output for your javascript strings:

```
<script>
    var oGlobalStrings = {
            some_data : '<?=$this->lang->line('some_data_language_key');?>'
        }
</script>
```

Then you can use it throughout your Javascript app using the syntax:

```
oGlobalStrings.some_data
```

Works very well and can be handled very easily throughout your app.